# Managing application versions using Conan and RPM

Tags: c++, programming-practices, patterns-and-practices, versioning, organization

I have a shared object that I developed.  This shared object is packaged in two forms, a Conan package, and an RPM.  It is a Qt project, so it has a .pro file associated with it.  Up until now, we have managed our dependency versions through the .pro file by defining:

```
MAJOR = 1
MINOR = 2
PATCH = 3
```

but now, with Conan and RPM, it is becoming a bit of a nightmare to maintain.  Should we still be managing the version from the .pro file and scraping the version out for the Conan package version and the RPM version or should we have a separate version file that anything that needs it can use.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you mean by "scraping."

Comment: I just meant a common file they all could use

Comment: What do you think it would take to ease the nightmare?